# Remove() does not work on a many-to-many relationship (ASP.NET, lambda expressions)

Tags: c#, asp.net, lambda

I am working with C# and ASP.net (4.0). I am trying to remove a record in my InterestsProfiles table using lambda expressions. The table has only two columns: profile id and interest id, and these are foreign keys to the Profiles table (id) and the Interests table (id).

So I managed to add to the Interests profiles table with the following code (the arguments to the function are string profileID, string name (of the interest)):

```
var interest = 
    context.a1Interests.Where(i => i.Interest.ToLower() == name.ToLower()).First();
if (interest == null)
  throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

// Grab the profile
a1Profile profile = context.a1Profiles.Find(_id);
// Create a new profile that will be modified
a1Profile newProfile = profile;
if (profile == null)
  throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

// Associate the interest with this profile
newProfile.a1Interests.Add(interest);

// Replace the old profile with the new one and save the changes
context.Entry(profile).CurrentValues.SetValues(newProfile);
context.SaveChanges();
```

I thought I could just do the opposite for removal, using .Remove(), but it does not work. The function returns the correct object and the status is 200/OK, but the entry in InterestsProfiles itself is not deleted.

```
newProfile.a1Interests.Remove(interest);

// Replace the old profile with the new one and save the changes
context.Entry(profile).CurrentValues.SetValues(newProfile);
context.SaveChanges();
```

The creation script for the table is this:

```
CREATE TABLE a1InterestsProfiles(
[Profile] [int] NOT NULL,
[Interest] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_a1InterestsProfiles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    ([Profile] ASC, [Interest] ASC)
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) 
ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]
GO 

-- Foreign key - Profiles
ALTER TABLE a1InterestsProfiles
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_a1InterestsProfiles_Profiles] 
FOREIGN KEY ([Profile]) REFERENCES a1Profiles([ID])
GO
ALTER TABLE a1InterestsProfiles CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_a1InterestsProfiles_Profiles]
GO

-- Foreign key - Interests
ALTER TABLE a1InterestsProfiles
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_a1InterestsProfiles_Interests]
FOREIGN KEY ([Interest]) REFERENCES a1Interests ([ID])
GO
ALTER TABLE a1InterestsProfiles CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_a1InterestsProfiles_Interests]
GO
```

Please help. I thought this would be really straightforward.

Comment: What data access technology are you using? LINQ-to-SQL, LINQ-to-Entities, or something else?

Comment: sq33G: It returns the object it's supposed to and a 200/OK status, but the entry in InterestsProfiles is not deleted.

Comment: Kirk Broadhurst: I'm afraid I do not know the terminology. If it helps, I created an ADO.NET Entity Data Model, and from the edmx file, the classes were created with ADO.NET DbContext Generator.

Comment: @daoberes if you tag names of other posters with @, your comment will show up in their SO inbox.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `.Attach()` and entity when editing it;

to add

```
a1Profile profile = context.a1Profiles.Find(_id);
a1Profile.a1Interests.Add(interest);
context.SaveChanges();
```

to remove

```
newProfile.a1Interests.Remove(interest);
context.a1Profiles.Attach(newProfile);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Also worth looking at `EntityState.Modified`